# How to send mp3 file using a POST request from android studio to flask server

Tags: java, android, python, flask

I am running a flask server on my Raspberry Pi. I would like to send an mp3 file from android phone to raspberry pi using my app. I have successfully read the mp3 file into InputStream object. I would like to know how to send this object to Pi

Comment: 100% same wayy as any other file. mp3 has nothing special

Answer (score 0):

You will be using multipart upload to upload the .mp3 file

I would recommend you to use ION for uploading to the server.

EXAMPLE

```
Ion.with(getContext())
.load("POST" , "//your server address)
.setMultipartParameter("key", "value")
.setMultipartFile("name which is used in flask server to distinguish data", "audio/mp3", new File("//location of file"))
.asJsonObject()
.setCallback(...)
```

REFER: https://github.com/koush/ion for more